# Facebook Graph API - Is it possible to get the "suggest bid" for an ad set?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to get the suggested bid of an ad_set from the graph or through the facebook ads php sdk api? I would like to create an app that queries the api daily to get the "suggested bid" from all of my ad sets. This would help to track if competition rises or decreases for the targeting of my ad sets.

I have searched the facebook developer docs but have not been able to find this information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's an API for that purpose, the reach estimate also includes info about the suggested bid range for that set of targeting options

You can query for both an existing ad, and for a set of targeting options not currently applied to an ad

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reachestimate/v2.5

Sample call:

```
curl -G \
  -d 'currency=USD' \
  -d 'optimize_for=OFFSITE_CONVERSIONS' \
  --data-urlencode 'targeting_spec={ 
    "geo_locations": {"countries":["US"]}, 
    "age_min": 20, 
    "age_max": 40 
  }' \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/reachestimate
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": 186000000,
    "bid_estimations": [
      {
        "unsupported": false,
        "location": 3,
        "bid_amount_min": 39,
        "bid_amount_median": 80,
        "bid_amount_max": 121
      }
    ],
    "estimate_ready": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of v2.10 this is now [/AD_ACCOUNT/delivery_estimate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/delivery_estimate) or [/AD_SET/delivery_estimate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/delivery_estimate/)

Example response:

```
    {
  "data":[
    {
      "bid_estimate":{
        "min_bid":151,
        "median_bid":246,
        "max_bid":405
      },
      "daily_outcomes_curve":[
        {
          "spend":0,
          "reach":0,
          "impressions":0,
          "actions":0
        },
        {
          "spend":157,
          "reach":32768.790689652,
          "impressions":90945.104519826,
          "actions":90945.104519826
        },
        {
          "spend":239,
          "reach":35937.659450005,
          "impressions":126453.01012466,
          "actions":126453.01012466
        },
        {
          "spend":495,
          "reach":52682.097382142,
          "impressions":178817.36771853,
          "actions":178817.36771853
        },
        ...
```

+1 to Igy for the reference link, which is now here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting/v2.10